# Is it sane to use React `context` to access model mutators in a Flux-less app?

Tags: reactjs, redux, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm starting a new React app and, seeing all the news in the ecosystem, I want to go slow and actually consider my choices, starting with just React/Webpack/Babel, and introducing more.

The first of these choices is whether to use Flux or not (more precisely, Redux, which looks great and seems to have won the flux wars). Here is where I am:

1. I understand Redux's benefits, [summarized on SO by Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461229/why-use-redux-over-facebook-flux/32920459#32920459). They look great, but I'd rather introduce things one step at a time.
2. In plain React, parent→child communication is done with props, and child→parent communication happens with callbacks. See [Doc / Communicate Between Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html), or [SO / Child to parent communication in React (JSX) without flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37357249/child-to-parent-communication-in-react-jsx-without-flux), or [this codeacademy Redux tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w-oQ-i1XB8) which starts out by saying *"no need for Redux if you're fine with plain React and all your data in a root component"*.

   - Which looks just fine for my purpose...
   - ... **however**, the sad part is that these callbacks have to be passed down the component chain, which becomes quickly [tedious as the levels of nesting grow](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8564802).

To solve this without introducing new dependencies, I found two articles ([1: Andrew Farmer](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#8-context), [2: Hao Chuan](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:DrdSe2QcpgIJ:haochuan.io/how-to-communicate-between-pure-react-components-without-flux/+&cd=10&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)) encouraging usage of the recently-introduced [context feature of React](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html).

→ Using `context` would let me expose my model-mutating callbacks to my child components. To me it doesn't sound like a horrible misuse: I wouldn't be passing model data, just references to functions for binding on event handlers.

- Does it sound sane?
- Any other plain-React suggestion for convenient child→parent communication?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question after watching Dan Abramov's [Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux) series, which I warmly recommend.

**Yes it looks like it's sane: Redux faced the very same problem and solved it with `Context`** (at least initially, the implementation may have changed). It is implemented and packaged (among other things) in the `react-redux` bindings under the `<Provider>` component and the `connect()` function.

1. Initially, at the start of step [24 - Passing the Store Down Explicitly via Props](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-extracting-container-components-visibletodolist-addtodo) , we have a Todo app with a Redux store available as top-level variable. This sucks (for 1. testability/mockability, 2. server rendering needing *"a different store instance for every request because different requests have different data"*), so the store is demoted from top-level variable to a root component prop.
2. As in my case, having to pass the store as prop to each component is annoying, so in [25 - Passing the Store Down Implicitly via Context](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-implicitly-via-context), Dan demonstrates using `Context` to pass the Redux store to arbitrarily nested components.
3. It is followed by [26 - Passing the Store Down with `<Provider>` from react-redux](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-passing-the-store-down-with-provider-from-react-redux), explaining how this was encapsulated in the `react-redux` bindings.
4. And [27 - Generating Containers with `connect()` from React Redux](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-generating-containers-with-connect-from-react-redux-visibletodolist) further encapsulates generation of a container component from a presentational component.

Comment: The important thing to remember with context is that you don't get the automatic re-rendering behaviour you do with props. If shouldComponentUpdate returns false somewhere in your tree, the children won't render even if the context has changed. Redux (and Facebook Flux, etc.) works around this by updating the 'state' of any connected component in response to store state changes, triggering the 'connect'ed sub-tree to re-render if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I find the question quite simple to answer, if you think about the way dependency injection in Angular works. In Angular you have your DOM, and then you have all those services, providers, factories, constants and whatnot, which are independent of the DOM structure and can be imported simply by mentioning their name when creating modules or controllers.

I liken the use of `this.context` to DI. The difference w.r.t to Angular is that instead of stating the dependencies using function parameter names, you use `childContextTypes` and instead of getting the dependencies as function arguments, you get them through `this.context`.

In this sense, asking the question whether passing model mutators through `this.context` is sane, boils down to whether it makes sense in Angular to register your model for dependency injection. I've never seen a problem with the latter, therefore I deduce that the former is also quite OK.

I'm not saying that it suits the spirit of the library, though. Dependency injection and in particular managing dependencies between injected component is not as explicit, so one may argue that it's not the React way. I leave this philosophical discussion to others.